# use numbering instead of italics in a subsection

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have the following problem:

The following LaTeX code:

```
\section{A Section with some Tables} 

In this section we present the results of our computations for the Coxeter
groups of types $B_3$, $H_3$, $B_4$, $D_4$, $F_4$, and $H_4$, thus verifying
Theorem~\autoref{thm:main} for irreducible Coxeter groups of rank three and
four.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{$W$ of type $B$}
\label{BTheorySection}
Assume now that $V$ is the reflection representation of $W=W(B_n)$ with
$n\geq 2$ and let $\{\, v_1, \dots, v_n\,\}$ be a basis of $V$.  We view $W$
as acting on $V$ by signed permutations of $\{\,v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\,\}$.
Namely, the Coxeter generators $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n$ are given by
```

Produces the following output:
[image]

I want the the subsection to be numbered instead of being in italics, in this case the desire output should be:

2.2 A section with some Tables

...

2.2.1 W of type B

...

You can find my LaTeX files in the following link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iz7w3lwr65yds87/fancy.zip The file to compile is called "fancydissertation.tex"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not everybody wants to download zip files from somewhere. Please provide a reduced MWE that shows your problem.

Comment: The italics come from the fact, that you use `mathmode` for `W` etc. And the missing number: Either you use `\subsection*{....}` or the corresponding counter is `dead` ;-)

Comment: Most probably you have `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` which turns the numbering of the subsections off, since `1` stands for sections, `2` is correct for subsections etc.

Comment: I am not using `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` and `\subsection*{....} ` is still showing the subsection in italics, not in numbering format.

Comment: In the file UNTdissertation.sty, line 213:`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}`. That is the cause of the missing number. Your dissertation `*.tex` file `inputs` that file

Comment: so to fix the problem, should I just eliminate the line?

Comment: No, just say after `\input{UNTdissertation.sty}` `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` or use a higher number, if there are `subsubsection`s also. And better change `\input{UNTdissertation.sty}` to `\usepackage{UNTdissertation}`.

Comment: Thank you, now the numbering is working but the text still in italics, as showin in [link](http://imgur.com/LpDKkQr). The subsection also does not appear in the contents section (index) any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: There is an answer to the `italics` issue. For toc use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` as well

Comment: I am using: `\input{UNTdissertation.sty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` and I still have the italics issue.

Comment: The italics issue is addressed by the answer below, not by setting counters ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UNTdissertation.sty` you have:

```
%%% This redefines the \subsection command so that it's flush left and
%%% italicized.
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.35\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.25\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
```

Hence it is not a bug, it is a feature. If your really dislike it (and like the mentioned style), you can redefine it again. 
After long battle I (I hope) understand, what do you want. Then you should replace the above lines by

After a long battle I understand (I hope), what are you going to have. Hence you should replace the above lines by

```
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.35\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.25\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\itshape}}
 {\normalfont}}
```

*Remark:* I hope that the linked ZIP file will be obtainable in the future. It may help the next users. (And the staff is beautiful).

Comment: how can I redefine it? I want the subsections to be numbered without italics and make them appear in the contents section (index)?

Comment: @user3025898: Just copy the lines from the examples Przemyslaw gave you, after `\input{UNTdissertation.sty}` and interchange `\normalfont\itshape` or better, drop `\itshape` ;-)

Comment: @user3025898 The simplest way is to rename UNTdissertation.sty, put information, that it is not the original one near begining, and comment lines from my answer (lines 224-226 from the original style).

Comment: @user3025898 And THIS part of code should be changed.

Comment: what do you mean with "put information, that it is not the original one near begining"?? I commented the lines 224 to 226 of UNTdissertation.sty and the problem still stands.

Comment: @user3025898: Add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` to your preamble, which should show the subsection's number when you use `\subsection{...}`.

Comment: @user3025898: Przemyslaw just suggested to make a backup copy of your `UNTdissertation.sty` and work with the original one, editing in the way he mentioned, i.e. commenting those lines `\renewcommand{\subsection}` and the following 2 lines as well.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Sorry, I can't reproduce that special `l` (Polish?) character ;-)

Comment: Now the text is showing in bold http://imgur.com/EiFbrVv I want it with out bold. any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: @user3025898: Uncomment the lines again and remove `\itshape` in the last line there, it should be in normalfont, not bold then.

Comment: @user3025898 See the enlarged answer. And \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} in your preamble is the second change to do.

Comment: Thank you Christian and Przemysław it is working as it should now!

Comment: @user3025898 You are welcome. And the first three funny pages are from the original template or it is your joke?

Comment: is the original template provided by my university :P A guy with a great sense of humor created this...

Answer (score 0):

complete fix including subsubsection:

```
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.35\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.25\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\itshape}}
 {\normalfont}}

   \renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
  \z@{.35\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.25\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont}}
```